# How to move an Android application hosted at Play Store from internal testing to production?

Tags: android, google-play

How to move an Android application hosted at Play Store from internal testing to production?
It is showing error if I am uploading the same APK in production and asking to change the key.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your internal test track. Next to the "View release details" there's a dropdown list called "Promote release". All you have to do is select Production and follow the instructions.

If you want to upload a new APK you have to make sure that it has a unique version code.

Comment: Production button is disabled. I can see closed testing while alpha is disabled these as well

Comment: Have you filled out all the required fields under "Store presence"? Have you completed all the forms under "App content"? Also make sure that you don't have any issues posted under "Policy status".